# Azure Function in .Net 6 giving error Could not load file or assembly

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I am getting this error in my Azure Function while running on .NET 6 on Windows:

[image]

> The 'Function1' function is in error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The function is in proc with `HttpTrigger`:

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
            ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
            : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the dll Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 8.0.0.0 in your project?

Comment: Yes added that and still getting the error

Comment: @PrasanjeetDebnath please check this [link](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2319#issuecomment-1378025573), its a limitation for in-process function Model. To get your function work, you can either delete Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions or move this function to isolated function model

Comment: @iktesam . thanks for the info. I have change my approach as per the link

Answer (score 1):

***Converting my comments into answer to help the community***

If you are creating a default In-process function then your .csproj should look like below-

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>_77388945</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

As per this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2319#issuecomment-1378025573),  `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` is not supported for In-process function. So, either you can delete this package from your existing function or you can create an [Isolated function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) if you want to use this package.

I am able to get the output using the below code and above given .csproj file.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace company
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

***Output***-

[image]

[image]